# Execute templates multiple times with BigQuery as sink

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

For BigQuery batch pipelines, templates can only be executed once, as the BigQuery job ID is set at template creation time. I am using Apache beam v2.0.0 and not able to execute the template multiple time. Can we use beam at head for this restriction? If yes, first thing that I'd like to know is what is beam at head? And what are the exact changes required in my Apache Beam program to support template execution multiple times?

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jms</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-examples-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-examples-java8</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-common-fn-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-build-tools</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-join-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-sorter</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-amqp</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-kafka</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-kinesis</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-mqtt</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-solr</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-core-construction-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-core-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-common-runner-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is issue [BEAM-2058](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2058). It should be fixed if you use the latest code from the [Beam github repository](https://github.com/apache/beam). You shouldn't need to do anything other than build the a new version of Beam and update your pom.xml to use that.

Alternatively, wait for the 2.1.0 release of Beam, which is being prepared.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my pom.xml file based on pom.xml file present in the github repository but still facing the same issue. On the github repository, multiple code components are presents under different folders. Could you please let me know the exact path for latest code so that I can use it in my DataFlow program? Also, please let me know exact which snippet I need to add (from the GitHub code) in my DF program to resolve the template execution issue? 
Sorry I am new to github. Can you please help me out with it

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify any of your code based on what is in Github. Instead, you need to clone the github repository and install it using Maven. This will make the 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT version available to your code. Then you just update your pom.xml to reference the 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT version of Beam that you built, and use that.

Comment: The [Beam contribution guide](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/contribution-guide/#one-time-setup) also talks about the steps necessary to build Beam from the Github code repository, which may help with the steps necessary to install the latest version. Once you've done that, you shouldn't need to make any changes to your project other than using the new version you built.

Comment: Thank you. I cloned the github repository and install it using Maven. Also updated pom.xml file to add dependency still getting below error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.beam.sdk.common.runner.v1.RunnerApi$FunctionSpec$‌​Builder.setParameter‌​(Lcom/google/protobu‌​f/Any;)Lorg/apache/b‌​eam/sdk/common/runne‌​r/v1/RunnerApi$Funct‌​ionSpec$Builder;" Note: Updated POM.xml file has been added to the question.

Comment: I also tried one more option. Downloaded all code from github and created new Java project. After this, I created the Jar file which I imported to my DataFlow program as external Jar file. Still i am not able to execute the same template multiple time. Please let me know if there is any other option or workaround. thanks

Comment: Please let me know how to resolve NoSuchMethodError or suggest any alternate way to resolve the template execution issue. Thanks in advance